# Java/ Javascript from String to time

Tags: javascript, java, datetime

I want to do some time manipulation which to add 30 minutes to the time given in String format, so I do some test data to print from 12.00am to 12.00pm.The following code produce unsatisfied result which will auto remove the "0" if less than 9.

```js
ConvertTimeformat("24", "12.00am");

function ConvertTimeformat(format, time) {
 var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
 var minutes = Number(time.match(/\.(\d+)/)[1]);
 var AMPM = time.match(/\D(\D.*)$/)[0];
 var a = document.getElementById("time");
 var text = "";
 if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12)
  hours = hours + 12;
 if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12)
  hours = hours - 12;

 for(var i = 1;i <= 48; i++){
  minutes += 30;
  if(minutes == 60){
   hours += 1;
   minutes = 00;
  }


  text += hours+""+minutes+"<br/>";

 }

 a.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id="time"><p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I try to do the following to add if-statement, to add "0" if less the 9, but the result was terrible.

```js
ConvertTimeformat("24", "12.00am");

function ConvertTimeformat(format, time) {
 var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
 var minutes = Number(time.match(/\.(\d+)/)[1]);
 var AMPM = time.match(/\D(\D.*)$/)[0];
 var a = document.getElementById("time");
 var text = "";
 if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12)
  hours = hours + 12;
 if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12)
  hours = hours - 12;

 for(var i = 1;i <= 48; i++){
  minutes += 30;
  if(minutes == 60){
   hours += 1;
   minutes = 00;
  }

  if(minutes == 0){
   minutes = "00";
  }

  if(hours <= 9){
   hours = "0" + hours;
  } 

  text += hours+""+minutes+"<br/>";

 }

 a.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id="time"><p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have ideas to modify my code to look more better? This code will be use in Java as well, so how is the syntax run? Same as Javascript? Thank you

[UPDATE] The expected outcome should be:

```
0000
0030
0100
0130
.
.
.
0000
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different languages.  A program is generally one or the other (or something else).  With the exception of some very trivial examples, source code won't run correctly in both languages.

Comment: Also, you won't get an answer here unless you clarify exactly what your program is doing wrong, and what you want it to do differently.  Just "modify my code to look more better" doesn't tell anyone what you actually want.

Comment: Have you looked at [SimpleDateFormat and SimpleDateFormat.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?